# Creating a new column and pasting data into that new column with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to create a new column on a different sheet and then copy data into that column.

Below is the code I have written. The first sub is a new column to the left and the second sub is the column to the right.

The insert column part is working. I hid a column and have a cell in there as a named range which I used to select in my macro. The data I want to copy is on the Input sheet and is named InputData.

```vb
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Set sourceSheet = ActiveSheet
Sheets("Data").Activate
Sheets("Data").Range("DividerColumn").Select
Selection.EntireColumn.Offset(0, 0).Insert Shift:=xlToLeft
'Sheets("Input").Activate
'Range("InputData").Copy
'Sheets("Data").Activate
'ActiveCell offset maybe?
'Range().PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Call sourceSheet.Activate

End Sub
```

```vb
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet

Set sourceSheet = ActiveSheet

Sheets("Data").Activate

Sheets("Data").Range("DividerColumn").Select

Selection.EntireColumn.Offset(0, 1).Insert Shift:=xlToRight

Call sourceSheet.Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: What's not working the way you expect? FYI there's probably hundreds of answers on StackOverflow that answer in some variation copying values, columns, formats between sheets.

Comment: @pgSystemTester I have been looking but most of the questions asked are using a static column. When I run the insert column macro it changes the column to a new one and I can't find something to select that new column. I have seen some last column functions but the issue is the new columns being inserted are in the middle of a data set not at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Oh I didn't see your copy range. In that case this could probably work. I see you just got the answer, but this would be a good way to avoid select.

```
Sub copyToLeft()
   Call doTheCopy(False)
End Sub
Sub CopyToRight()
   Call doTheCopy(True)
End Sub

Private Sub doTheCopy(goRightIsTrue As Boolean)
   With Sheets("Data").Range("DividerColumn").EntireColumn.Offset(0, IIf(goRightIsTrue, 1, 0))
      .Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
      .Offset(0, -1).Value = Sheets("Input").Range("InputData").EntireColumn.Value
   End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by using an offset function. Below is my code. Hope this helps someone with a similar situation.

```
   Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
   Set sourceSheet = ActiveSheet
   Sheets("Data").Activate
   Sheets("Data").Range("DividerColumn").Select
   Selection.EntireColumn.Offset(0, 0).Insert 
   Shift:=xlToLeft
   Sheets("Input").Activate
   Range("InputData").Copy
   Sheets("Data").Activate
   Range("DividerColumn").Select
   ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).PasteSpecial 
   xlPasteValues
   Call sourceSheet.Activate

   End Sub
```

-1 in the offset function moves your active cell to the left one cell and then 1 moves it to the right. So once the column is created, either right or left, my macro goes and copies the information and then goes back to the sheet I want it to and selects my named range again and then it gets moved to the left and pastes my data.

Comment: You'll want to try to avoid using select, and probably copy paste as you get more advanced, but good job finding solution.